# llave foránea null

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]A ver si me podéis ayudar con lo siguiente:

Quiero insertar el `id` de una tabla a otra, con un `INSERT INTO` y una subconsulta `SELECT`, la cual hace referencia a esa id deseado mediante una llave foránea.

Mi consulta SQL captura tal `id`, lo graba en su tabla correspondiente pero no se refleja en la tabla que hace referencia a ese `id`. Sin embargo, cuando hago otra consulta SQL y hago referencia a ese `id` que antes mostraba `NULL`, entonces se muestra en la tabla que tiene la llave foránea. En una imagen se inserta todo, en la segunta también, solo que en la primera los dos primeros ids referenciados por defecto no se muestran(fk_expositor, fk_serie) que es lo que intento que no sea así

Con el código que os dejo a ver si me puedo explicar mejor

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

       $nombre_audio=($_POST['nombre_audio']);
       $cargarAudio = $_FILES['audio']['tmp_name'];
       $audio = fopen($cargarAudio,'rb');
       $nombre_expositor = ($_POST['nombre_expositor']);
       $nombre_serie = ($_POST['nombre_serie']);
    // $fecha_bd=date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");

    if (empty($nombre_audio) && empty($audio) && empty($nombre_expositor)) {
        unset($_POST);
        echo "<h3>Todos los campos son obligatorios</h3>";

    }else{ 

        $sql2 = "INSERT IGNORE  INTO expositor(nombre_expositor) VALUES ('$nombre_expositor')";
        $sql3 = "INSERT IGNORE  INTO serie(nombre_serie) VALUES ('$nombre_serie')";

        $sql = "INSERT   INTO audio (nombre_audio, audio, fk_expositor, fk_serie) 
                VALUES ('$nombre_audio', '$audio', (SELECT id_expositor FROM expositor WHERE nombre_expositor = '$nombre_expositor'), 
                (SELECT id_serie FROM serie WHERE nombre_serie = '$nombre_serie'))";




        if ($conexion->query($sql) === TRUE &&
             $conexion->query($sql2) === TRUE
             && $conexion->query($sql3) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";



        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conexion->error;
            echo "<h3>Todos los campo son obligatorios</h3>";
        }


    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: Hay varias cosas que podrías considerar corregir. 1.- No estas validando que NO exista un `expositor` con el mismo nombre. 2.- Tu sub-consulta en el `INSERT` de `audio` no tiene `LIMIT`, por lo que si existe más de un `expositor` con el mismo nombre, fallaría. 2.1.- Podrías hacer el `INSERT` del `expositor` y obtener el `id` para ahorrarte la sub-consulta en el `INSERT` del `audio`. Por otro lado, no termino de entender cual es el problemas. ¿Podrías incluir un ejemplo de como quedan los datos después del proceso y cual es el resultado esperado?

Comment: Vale, no se como se integra el LIMIT, tendré que mirar la documentación. --- @Marcos 'Podrías hacer el INSERT del expositor y obtener el id para ahorrarte la sub-consulta en el INSERT del audio'----- eso se me cruzó por la mente al comienzo pero quería hacerlo todo en uno, es decir, que al insertar un audio, a su vez capture el id de expositor y serie que también se crearían con el mismo envío del formulario.  Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo, pareciera que quieres:

- insertar un nuevo registro en `expositor` usando `$nombre_expositor`
- insertar otro en  `serie` con `$nombre_serie`,
- tomar los ID autogenerados producto de la inserción
- usar los dos ID más los dos nombre para crear un registro en `audio`

Efectivamente, como te dijeron en los comentarios, si los nombres no son únicos tu insert no se comportará cómo esperas. Suponiendo que hay 2 registros con el mismo nombre expositor y nombre serie respectivamente, una consulta del tipo:

```
SELECT '$audio' as  audio,
       '$nombre_audio' as nombre_audio,
       id_expositor,
       id_serie
FROM expositor
JOIN serie ON expositor.nombre_expositor = '$nombre_expositor' 
           AND serie.nombre_serie = '$nombre_serie'
```

Tendría 4 registros. (pero todos ellos tendrán una llave foránea válida). Como imagino que no es lo que quieres, en realidad tu **problema 1** está acá:

```
 if (
     $conexion->query($sql) === TRUE &&
     $conexion->query($sql2) === TRUE &&
     $conexion->query($sql3) === TRUE
 )
```

- necesitas ejecutar $sql2 para que exista un id_expositor
- necesitas ejecutar $sql3 para que exista un id_serie
- tú ejecutas $sql primero y los id no existen aún.

Si hicieras en cambio:

```
 if (
     $conexion->query($sql2) === TRUE &&
     $conexion->query($sql3) === TRUE &&
     $conexion->query($sql) === TRUE
 )
```

Funcionaría. **Pero hay una manera mejor.**

```
if(!$conexion->query($sql2)) {
    echo "Error: " . $sql2. "<br>" . $conexion->error;
    return;
}
$id_expositor = $conexion->insert_id; // (último ID generado por la query);

if(!$conexion->query($sql3)) {
    echo "Error: " . $sql3. "<br>" . $conexion->error;
    return;
}
$id_serie= $conexion->insert_id; // (último ID generado, que cambió con la nueva sentencia);
```

Con eso ya tienes las cuatro variables y no necesitas meter las dos tablas en la consulta de inserción. Sin embargo tienes además un problema al interpolar variables en forma artesanal. Inyecciones SQL por ejemplo.

Para eso, suponiendo que estás usando `MySQLi` se usan sentencias preparadas.

```
   $sql2 = "INSERT IGNORE  INTO expositor(nombre_expositor) VALUES (?)";

   $stmt2 = $conexion->prepare($sql2);
   $stmt2->bind_param('s',$nombre_expositor);
   $stmt2->execute();
```

Acá no sé si puedes obtener el ID con `$conexion->insert_id` o se hace con `$stmt2->insert_id`. Debiera funcionar con ambas.

Y cuando ya tengas las cuatro variables para insertar en `audio`

```
   $sql = "INSERT  INTO audio (nombre_audio, audio, fk_expositor, fk_serie)     
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

   $stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql);

   $stmt->bind_param('ssdd',$nombre_audio, $audio, $id_expositor', $id_serie);
   $stmt->execute();
```

Si estás usando PDO todo es igual salvo que para obtener el ID lo harías con 
`$conexion->lastInsertId`;

#### And there's one more thing

Si estás usando INSERT IGNORE ¿será que el nombre del expositor y la serie son llaves únicas? En ese caso, cuando se ignore la consulta por llave duplicada, **el último ID de inserción será cero.**

Eso se resuelve con:

```
  INSERT INTO expositor(nombre_expositor) VALUES (?)
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id_expositor);
```

En el fondo no modificaste el registro pero sí obtienes el último ID de inserción del registro que provocaba el IGNORE.

Comment: wow, Eso es lo que estaba procurando. Lo probaré. Muchas gracias @amenadiel